# Can I schedule a BigQuery query to run after the Firebase export completes?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have noticed inconsistent completion times on the Google owned and run daily Firebase export from Firebase to BigQuery.  Is there a way to schedule my custom queries to run X minutes after that data export occurs?

I have asked Firebase Support but have been told that I need to speak with BigQuery Support on this matter.  They also told me there was no way to manually change the data export completion time.

Comment: There is a signup link for an early access to an alpha: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcnKD6Oak51o3I8a5-bwT9AeVp1V04ulSux_GR1lGn1hALrg/viewform Once you signup up and you are added into the group, more information can be shared with you. Ask the Q in the group. Using the feature of alpha you are able to accomplish what you want.